# Using the Google Users Service with jQuery Mobile

Tags: google-app-engine, jquery-mobile

I was wondering what would be a better way to let my jQuery Mobile app "know" the user of the app after completing a registration process.Since the handlers in my Python Google App Engine app expect a username, i decided to store the username in `localstorage` and then use this as part of any request made to the server.But i don't think this is a good design idea (?).After a lot of search, i have found that jQuery Mobile does not support Google login (Please correct me if am wrong) So i have decided to use the `Users Service` from the server end.I am confused on how to implement this, since the `users` service from Google has it's own sign-in form.
Is it possible to use this same service with jQuery? If so, can i change the design of the sign-in form to blend in with the design of my jQuery app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery Mobile is just a template designer created directly for mobile web applications using a mobile web browser. It does not possess any connections with server side scripting automatically.

You need to create a connection using server side scripting.

Once you login in using the Google Login, your app associates it with the Google account.

jQuery is just a browser scripting. It does not have an automatic connection with the server unless you connect using AJAX to request to a server, but still need to code the server using HTTP protocol (as a tunnel) and server side scripting language like Java, Python, or PHP.

If you just want to get the "username" using a javascript, you may use REST to get the user information after login. You may look for how JSON or XML REST is created (but putting the username on local storage is not a bad option, without the password, however it may get deleted if you clear the root), but knowing that you are already connected with Google Sign in, just as long as you are already logged in with Google, your app should be able to retrieve the Google username.

Udacity also contains a complete course about web development focused on Google App Engine using Python, and how you may use cookies, password encryption, as well as user login. A detailed information about HTTP protocol is also discussed.

https://www.udacity.com/course/cs253

Note that the course I took existed 2 years ago. It may be different now.

Comment: My point is, my GAE app does not have a user interface.Interaction with the app is done strictly from the jQuery mobile app.Since the Users service can only be done on the server side, how do i even get someone to sign in from the jQuery app?

Comment: Because jQuery Mobile is using JavaScript and/or jQuery, you may request an HTTP POST to sign in using AJAX. The most familiar framework for me is jQuery form plugin: http://jquery.malsup.com/form/. You may also use jQuery POST: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Comment: Please bear with me Franz, i don't think we are on the same page.I am not trying to create just any login function, i want to use Google's.If i request a sign-in using AJAX, where do i send the information entered into the form to? The Google User's service creates it's own form and accepts an email.It doesn't have any methods exposed to developers for saving information from a custom form.

Comment: Wait, are you saying that you can not see "Allow" or "Cancel" after clicking a button using jquery mobile? It does not move you to the next page where it says something like "Beware you're basic information will be shared"? From what I know, the login button is just a link. Therefore, you can just copy the link of Google login, and the users will go to a page where they will approve that they allow basic information to be shared with your app.